# javascript: Swap image & onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<img src="logo.jpg" class="myImage" alt="Logotyp" />
```

This is my javascript code:

```js
$(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth <= 480) {
        $(".myImage").attr("src", "load.jpg");
    }
});
```

The image logo.jpg becomes load.jpg when window width = 480. Works fine. But I want an onClick-function that says when you click load.jpg it becomes logo.jpg again. Can't seem to make it work. Suggestions?

Comment: consider using an ID in lieu of a class if you are only desiring 1 element to change.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".myImage").click(function(){
   $(this).attr("src"," logo.jpg"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ubakuc/2/edit)*

You can:

- create a var `windowWidth`
- create a function "`changeImg()`" that will handle transformations depending on the `windowWidth` var value.
- Than we use our function `changeImg()` wherever we want: we can do it also inside a `$(window).resize()` so the changes will be applied on manual re-size too.
- Than on click we play dirty, we fool the windowWidth setting a huge number and call our `changeImg` function. Fun.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  
  function changeImg(){
     if (windowWidth <= 480) {
        $(".myImage").attr("src", "http://www.rockettheme.com/distribution/download/file.php?avatar=63759_1251026504.jpg");
     }else{
        $(".myImage").attr("src", "http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/blog/en/2009/12/2t_firefox-logo.jpg");
     }
  }
  changeImg();
  
  $(window).resize(function(){
    windowWidth = $(window).width(); // grab width while resizeing
    changeImg();
  });
  
  $('img[alt=Logotyp]').on('click', function(){
    windowWidth = 9876; // we fool the windowWidth
    changeImg();    // we play dead and call our function :D
  });
  
});
```

Answer (score -1):

function myAlert() { alert("heelo wrold") };

$(.myImage).setAttribute ("onclick", "myAlert()");

Haven't tried this, but it seems right. ~Ben

Comment: your selector is wrong. also- just use the .bind('click', function(){}) or .click(function(){}) instead.